# Has anyone driven a bell or tuning fork using light?

Tags: electromagnetism, resonance, education

In principle a metal bell or tuning fork of sufficiently high quality factor could be driven by audio frequency radio waves of sufficient power to produce an audible hum. Has this been done, yet? If not, what combination of quality factor and transmission power would be needed to do this? Ideally, this would be done using far field components, so it would be photons and not the sort of near-field driving done in induction based transformers, but this requirement is not essential.

In principle, this is how ordinary speakers work, of course, as electromagnetic coils drive forces on magnets that are coupled to membranes. The main purpose of the question is about having that visible gap, and the object that is ringing for "no reason".

Comment: I suppose one could blacken one of the tines and modulate the light with the resonance frequency of the tuning fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about a resonance of a bell or tuning fork which is driven by an electromagnetic wave with a frequency equal to the natural frequency of the bell or tuning fork then the answer is probably   “It is not possible”.

If the natural frequency of the bell was $3000 \,\rm Hz$ then the wavelength of the electromagnetic wave would need to be $100 \, \rm km$ and so unless the bell was of roughly this size or bigger the interaction between the bell and the electromagnetic wave would be very, very small.

A problem might be that if the intensity of the electromagnetic waves is suffice to make the bell resonate other objects in the path of the electromagnetic wave, eg you, might be adversely affected?
Continuing this idea one has to realise that this could be the basis of a “weapon” which unfortunately means that government might be willing to spend a lot of money on research to perfect.
Electromagnetic “weapons” do exist, eg [this link](https://spectrum.ieee.org/aerospace/military/electromagnetic-warfare-is-here), but I could not find any of the frequencies to ring a bell.

Comment: However, the frequency of the electromagnetic wave does not have to be equal to the natural frequency of the bell or tuning fork - one can use modulated electromagnetic waves and nonlinear effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use, for example, photoacoustic effect in gas inside a resonator (https://www.ibp.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/ibp/de/documents/Kompetenzen/Akustik/Photoakustik/pdf1_tcm45-48829.pdf)